# With BeautifulSoup, how do I search for an element class wtihin a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm using Python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup 4.  I want to find all "div.title" elements that occur within "td.info" elements.  The CSS selector (I believe) would look like

```
td.info div.title
```

So I thought I could get the elements like this

```
elts = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "info"}).find("div", {"class": "title"})
for div in elts:
```

but instead I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/myproject/management/commands/runstats.py", line 11, in handle
    ret = MediaService.check_url("https://i.redd.it/wazz3axjtk331.jpg")
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/myproject/services/media_service.py", line 42, in check_url
    results = json.loads(MediaService.parseResults(code, True))
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/myproject/services/media_service.py", line 96, in parseResults
    elts = soup.findAll("td", {"class": "info"}).find("div", {"class": "title"})
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1621, in __getattr__
    "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

WHat gives?

Comment: Why not using `select()` method? `elts = soup.select('td.info div.title')`

Comment: Using select I would see if you can just use class as quicker elts = [item.text for item in soup.select('.info .title')] if after .text elts = [item['title'] for item in soup.select('.info .title')]  if after title attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use find() for td and find_all() for div element

```
elts = soup.find("td", class_="info").find_all("div", class_="title")
for div in elts:
    print(div['title'])
```

If you have multiple td tag and under td if you have multiple div tag try below.

---

```
for td in soup.find_all("td", class_="info"):
    for div in td.find_all("div", class_="title"):
        print(div['title'])
```

---

To use css

```
for td in soup.select("td.info"):
    for div in td.select("div.title"):
        print(div['title'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
soup.find_all(".class1.class2")
```